# Data loading in multiple fragments in ViewPager

Tags: android

I have Activity with ViewPager that holds 3 tabs of Fragments. Each of the fragments has its own URL where it needs to send request and fetch data in JSON format that is shown in Lists in each Fragment.
I am fetching the data in onCreateView and then populating the data in the ListView.
However the ViewPager simultaneously calls onCreateView of both adjacent Fragments due to which the progress bars of multiple Tabs clash and if there is exception in getting data in any one tab it clashes with other tab.

Should the better approach be that i create Objects of Fragments in my Activity and load data in activity and pass on the data to the Fragments as

```
Fragment one=FragmentOne.getInstance();
Fragment two=FragmentTwo.getInstance();

and after obtaining data ->
one.setData(Data)
two.setData(Data)
```

If anyone can guide how to do the same.
Thanks

Comment: ViewPager, are made with expectations to immediate swipe due to which adjacent fragments are loaded. so that if user swipe the relevant fragment should appear immediately. if you want to load your data when user goes to that fragment then instead of sending request for json in onCreateView or onActivityCreated keep it somewhere else where you will load when user request for that fragment

Comment: @PankajNimgade Thanks for your comment. The user does not request for data. when he changes tab we bring new data .just as you could imagine products for different categories in different tabs. where method in Fragment would be most appropriate for autoloading of data for it.